# Multiple problems with grub2 2.0x Multi-Boot-Installation under Ubuntu 2018LTS, 2019.04, 2019.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

First, I have some strategic questions:

1. The Ubuntu installers automatically invoke grub-install in UEFI mode on UEFI hardware, even if I want to install grub2 on an external SSD. Can I avoid this, i.e. use the legacy BIOS/MBR-mode grub2 booting? In my case, Ubuntu 2019.04 installed itself on an external SSD in MBR mode on an UEFI laptop and pointed the EFI partition to Windows’ GPT EFI partition (/dev/sdb1) so that I can only boot Ubuntu on that same laptop or on PCs with the same Windows GPT EFI partition.
2. Can grub2 cope flawlessly with MBR partition tables that were converted by gdisk to GPT and for which no space was reserved for EFI or grub2 partitions? Is it required to move existing partitions to make space for UEFI or grub2 partitions at the beginning of the disk?
   How can I tell grub2 to copy to an (external) SSD disk the contents of a Windows UEFI partition in an adapted form so it can boot in standalone boot as external SSD on a different PC/Laptop without Windows? Copying the partition with cp, tar or dd and calling grub-install did not work for me so far – resulting in the errors below. Must the flag --removable be used for an SSD?
3. Ideally, I would like to create a multi-boot system with Windows 10 and different Linux variants – all bootable by grub2. How do I do this to run as smoothly as possible?

   a) What should I do before installing Windows 10? Should I create a small GPT partition for grub2 and mark it as such? Should I create different EFI partitions, e.g. for Windows and the different Linux variants?

   b) Should I install Windows 10 before any Linux or vice versa?

   c) Is it possible to put an EFI partition into the logical partition space on an MBR SSD, e.g. as /dev/sda5?

   d) Must an EFI partition or a small GPT partition for grub2 be the first one on the disk/SSD (as some contradictory sources claim)?

   e) Is there an easy way to integrate a /boot partition back into the main Linux installation and telling grub2 about it? I figure that the hard way – once the grub2 install works – is to adapt the grub.cfg file accordingly and copying the files together into one partition.

I’m trying to repair a broken grub2 boot in /dev/sdb with any of the recent Ubuntu versions: I prepared these statements:
Configuration: /boot = /dev/sdb1, / = /dev/sdb3, UEFI = /dev/sdb4 (is created by this script)

```
sudo fdisk  /dev/sdb # possibly convert to GPT; create partition 4 of type EFI: code ef
sudo gdisk  /dev/sdb # create partition 4 of type EFI: code ef00
sudo partprobe
sudo mkdir -p /tmp/lin1/mnt/boot
sudo mount -o nouuid /dev/sdb3 /tmp/lin1 
sudo mount -o nouuid /dev/sdb1 /tmp/lin1/boot
sudo mkdir /tmp/lin1/mnt/boot
sudo mkfs.fat  /dev/sdb4
sudo mkdir -p /tmp/lin1/mnt/efi
sudo mount -o nouuid /dev/sdb4  /tmp/lin1/mnt/efi
sudo mount -o nouuid /dev/sdb1  /tmp/lin1/boot
sudo bash -c 'for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /bin /usr /var /etc; do mkdir -p  /tmp/lin1$i; done'
sudo bash -c 'for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /bin /usr /var /etc; do mount -o nouuid -B $i /tmp/lin1$i; done'
sudo chroot  /tmp/lin1/
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/tmp/lin1/mnt/efi --boot-directory=/tmp/lin1/boot --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb
sudo bash -c 'for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /bin /usr /var /etc; do umount  /tmp/lin1$i; done'
sudo umount /tmp/lin1/mnt/boot 
sudo umount /tmp/lin1/boot 
sudo umount /tmp/lin1/
sudo sync
sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdb
```

I run into these 7 problems (these problems all occur occasionally after pretty much the same grub-install as shown above, depending on host system, Ubuntu version, additional Windows10 UEFI partition present and if the SSD is connected internally or externally):

1. At boot time: a start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/…. (also
   after adapting the block ids in /etc/fstab)
2. Ubuntu systemd: Received SIGRTMIN+20 from PID (plymouthd)**
3. Ubuntu kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
4. Ubuntu kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM init failed (-110)
5. Grub: error: file ‘/grub2/i386-pc/normal.mod’ not found  - Entering rescue mode (the normal Ubuntu 2019.04 x64 EFI install
   directory is /grub/x86_64-efi)
6. Grub boot:**

   Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/CA82-D0E8
   Dependency failed for /boot/efi
7. chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: No such file or directory:

Problematic Part:

```
soc1@soc1-MS-7B17:/bin$ sudo chroot /tmp/lin1/ /usr/bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
soc1@soc1-MS-7B17:/bin$ ll /usr/bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1113504 Nov 20 20:00 /usr/bin/bash*
soc1@soc1-MS-7B17:/bin$ ll /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1113504 Jun 7 00:28 /bin/bash*
```

Diagnostic output:

```
soc1@soc1-MS-7B17:/bin$ strace -f chroot /tmp/lin1 /usr/bin/bash 2>&1
execve("/usr/sbin/chroot", ["chroot", "/tmp/lin1", "/usr/bin/bash"], 0x7fffe4c6c0f8 /* 62 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL) = 0x558749ead000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=74469, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 74469, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdf1d749000
close(3) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdf1d747000
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdf1d144000
mprotect(0x7fdf1d32b000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdf1d52b000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7fdf1d52b000
mmap(0x7fdf1d531000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdf1d531000
close(3) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fdf1d748540) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdf1d52b000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55874974a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdf1d75c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fdf1d749000, 74469) = 0
brk(NULL) = 0x558749ead000
brk(0x558749ece000) = 0x558749ece000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10281936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 10281936, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdf1c775000
close(3) = 0
lstat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/tmp/lin1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chroot("/tmp/lin1") = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096) = 0
close(3) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=578, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 578, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdf1d75b000
close(3) = 0
write(2, "chroot: ", 8chroot: ) = 8
write(2, "cannot change root directory to "..., 43cannot change root directory to '/tmp/lin1') = 43
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1
) = 1
close(1) = 0
close(2) = 0
exit_group(125) = ?
+++ exited with 125 +++
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at how sudodus does this in mkusb, source code is available. It boots both BIOS and UEFI.

Comment: I checked it out here, but it is so big and complex that I have difficulties extracting what is relevant for my project: https://github.com/tsimonq2/mkusb/blob/master/mkusb